# Ukkonen's algorithm for Generalized Suffix Trees

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

I am currently working on my own Suffix Tree implementation (using C++, but the question remains language agnostic). I studied [the original paper from Ukkonen](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf). The article is very clear so I got to work on my implementation and tried to tackle the problem for Generalized Suffix Trees.

In the tree, each substring leading from a node to another is represented using a pair of integer. While this is straightforward for a regular suffix tree,  a problem arises when multiple strings coexist in the same tree (which becomes a *Generalized Suffix Tree*). Indeed, now such a pair is not sufficient, we need another variable to state which reference string we are using.

A quick example. Consider the string `coconut`:

- The substring `nut` would be `(4,6)`.
- We add `troublemaker` in the tree, `(4,6)` can now be:

  - `nut` if we refer to the first string.
  - `ble` if we refer to the second string.

To handle this, I thought adding an id representing the string:

```cpp
// A pair of int is a substring (regular tree)
typedef std::pair<int,int> substring;
// We need to bind a substring to its reference string:
typedef std::pair<int, substring> mapped_substring;
```

The problem I currently face is the following:

I get a query to add a string in the tree. During the algorithm, I may have to inspect existing transitions related to other registered strings, represented as a triplet (*reference string id*, *k*, *p*). Some updating operations are based on the substrings indexes, **how can I perform them in such conditions**?

*Note: The question is language-agnostic so I did not include the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)-tag, though a little snippet is shown.*

Comment: You can just pretend that all strings appear as consecutive substrings in some order in a single large string (with each followed by its distinct termination symbol).  If you use a binary tree to map from positions in this large virtual string back to (string ID, pos), this will cost you a log(n) factor.  Lookups in the other direction can be done in O(1) with a table.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think that could be problematic with the "lazy" substring technique used (marking the end of the substring as `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` for example (infinity in the article).

Comment: I didn't read the paper, but I seem to vaguely recall that each string in a generalised suffix trees needs a distinct end marker.  If so, then you could use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - 1`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR

*EDIT (03/2019):* I have reworked my implementation to use C++17 `string_view` to represent my substrings along with a caching mechanism that makes sure reference strings do not move around. The updated version can be found on github: https://github.com/Rerito/suffix-tree-v2. Here is [the github for my old implementation (in C++)](https://github.com/Rerito/suffix-tree) for the curious minds. Oh and the new take also includes tests!

The original algorithm doesn't really need to be modified in order to build a *Generalized Suffix Tree*.

---

### Detailed analysis

The hunch I got was the right way. In order to keep up with the tricks used in the original algorithm, we indeed need to add a reference to the original string. Moreover, the algorithm is *online*, which means you can add strings on-the-fly to the tree.

Suppose we have a *Generalized Suffix Tree* GST(*N*) for strings (*S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>N</sub>*). The problem at hand here is how to handle the building process of GST(*N+1*), using GST(*N*).

### Tweaking the data model

In the simple case (single suffix tree), each transition is a couple (*substring*, *end vertex*). The trick in Ukkonen's algorithm is to model a substring using a pair of pointers to the appropriate positions in the original string. Here, we need to also link such a substring to its "parent" *string*. To do so:

- Store the original strings in a hash table, giving them a unique integer key.
- A substring becomes now: (ID, (left pointer, right pointer)). We can thus use ID to fetch the original string in *O(1)*.

We call this a *mapped substring*. The C++ typedefs I use are the ones found in my original question:

```cpp
// This is a very basic draft of the Node class used
template <typename C>
class Node {
    typedef std::pair<int, int> substring;
    typedef std::pair<int, substring> mapped_substring;
    typedef std::pair<mapped_substring, Node*> transition;
    // C is the character type (basically `char`)
    std::unordered_map<C, transition> g; // Called g just like in the article :)
    Node *suffix_link;
};
```

As you will see, we will keep the *reference pair* concept as well. This time, the *reference pair*, just like the transition, will hold a *mapped substring*.

*Note: As in C++, strings indexes will start at 0.*

---

### Inserting the new string

We want to insert *S<sub>N+1</sub>* into GST(*N*).
GST(*N*) may  have already a whole lot of nodes and transitions. In a simple tree, we would only have the root and the special sink node. Here, we may have transitions for *S<sub>N+1</sub>* that have already been added through the insertion of some previous strings. The first thing to do is to walk down the tree through the transitions as long as it matches *S<sub>N+1</sub>*.

By doing so, we end in a state *r*. This state may be explicit (i.e. we ended right on a vertex) or implicit (a mismatch occurred in the middle of a transition). We use the same concept as in the original algorithm to model such a state: *a reference pair*. Quick example:

- We want to insert *S<sub>N+1</sub>* = `banana`
- A node *s* representing `ba` *explicitly* exists in GST(*N*)
- *s* has a transition *t* for the substring `nal`

When we walk down the tree, we end up in the transition *t* at the character `l` which is a mismatch. Thus, the implicit state *r* we get is represented by the *reference pair* (*s*, *m*) where *m* is the mapped substring *(N+1, (1,3))*.

Here, *r* is the active point for the 5-th iteration of the algorithm in the building of `banana`'s suffix tree. The fact we got to that state means precisely that the tree for `bana` is already built in GST(*N*).

In this example, we resume the algorithm at the 5-th iteration, to build the suffix tree for `banan` using the tree for `bana`.  Not to lose the generality, we will state that *r* = *(s, (N+1, (k, i-1))*, *i* being the index of the first mismatch. We have indeed *k ≤ i* (the egality is synonym of *r* being an explicit state).

**Property: We can resume Ukkonen's algorithm to build GST(*N*) at iteration *i* (insertion of the character at index *i* in *S<sub>N+1</sub>*). The active point for this iteration is the state *r* we got by walking down the tree**. *The only tweaking needed is some fetching operations to resolve the substrings.*

---

### Proof for the property

First, the presence of such a state *r* implies that the whole states for the intermediate tree *T(N+1)<sup>i-1</sup>* are also there. So all is set up and we resume the algorithm.

We need to prove that each procedure in the algorithm remains valid. There are 3 such subroutines:

- `test_and_split`: given the character to insert at current iteration, test wether we need to split a transition into two separate transitions and if the current point is the end point.
- `canonize`: Given a *reference pair* *(n, m)* where *n* is a vertex and *m* a mapped substring, returns the couple *(n', m')* representing the same state such as *m'* is the shortest possible substring.
- `update`: Update GST(*N*) so that it has all the states for intermediate tree *T(N+1)<sup>i</sup>* at the end of the run.

### test_and_split

**Input:** A vertex *s*, a mapped substring *m = (l, (k, p))* and a character *t*.
**Output:** A boolean that tells if the state *(s, m)* is the end point for the current iteration and a node *r* representing explicitly *(s, m)* if it is not the end point.

The simplest case goes first. If the substring is empty (*k > p*), the state is already represented explicitly. We just have to test if we reached the end point or not. *In a GST, just like in a common suffix tree, there is **ALWAYS** at most one transition per node starting with a given character.* Thus, if there is a transition starting with *t*, we return true (we reached the end point), otherwise false.

Now the hard part, when k ≤ p. We first need to fetch the string *S<sub>l</sub>* lying at index *l***(*)** in the original strings table.
Let *(l', (k', p'))* (resp. *s'*) be the substring (resp. the node) related to the transition *TR* of *s* starting with the character *S<sub>l</sub>(k)* **(*)**. Such a transition exists because *(s, (l,(k,p))* represents an (existing) implicit state on the *border path* of the intermediate tree *T(N+1)<sup>i-1</sup>*. Furthermore, we are **sure** that the *p - k* first characters on this transition matches.

Do we need to split this transition? That depends on the *Δ = p - k + 1*-th character on this transition **(**)**. To test this character, we need to fetch the string lying at index *l'* on the hash table and get the character at index *k' + Δ*. This character is guaranteed to exist because the state we are examining is implicit and thus ends in the middle of the transition *TR* (Δ ≤ p' - k').

If the equality holds, we have nothing to do and return true (the end point is here) and do nothing else. If not, then we must split the transition and create a new state *r*. *TR* now becomes *(l', (k', k' + Δ - 1)) → r*. Another transition is created for *r*: *(l', (k' + Δ, p') → s'*. We now return false and *r*.

**(*)**: *l* is not necessarily equal to *N+1*. Likewise, *l* and *l'* may be different (or equal).

**(**)**: Notice that the number *Δ = p - k + 1* does not depend at all on the string chosen as a reference for the mapped substring. It only depends on the *implicit state* fed to the routine.

### Canonize

**Input:** A node _s_and a mapped substring *(l,(k,p))* representing an existing state *e* in the tree.
**Output:** A node *s'* and a mapped substring *(l',(k',p'))* representing the canonical reference for the state *e*

Using the same fetching tweaks, we just have to walk down the tree until we have *exhausted* the character "pool". Here, just like for `test_and_split` the unicity of each transition and the fact we have an existing state as input provides us with a valid procedure.

### Update

**Input:** The active point and the index for the current iteration.
**Output:** The active point for the next iteration.

`update` uses both `canonize` and `test_and_split` which are *GST-friendly*. The suffix link editing is exactly the same as the one for a common tree. The only thing to notice is that we will create the *open transitions* (i.e. the transitions leading to nodes) using *S<sub>N+1</sub>* as the reference string. Thus, at iteration *i*, the transition will always be linked to the mapped substring *(N+1,(i,∞))*

---

### Final step

We need to "close" the *open transitions*. To do so, we just traverse them and edit the ∞ away, replacing it with *L-1*, where *L* is the length of *S<sub>N+1</sub>*. We also need a sentinel character to mark the end of the string. A character we are sure to never meet in any string. This way, the leaves will remain leaves forever.

### Conclusion

The extra fetching work adds a few *O(1)* operations, increasing a little bit the constant factor of the complexity. Though, the asymptotic complexity remains obviously linear with the length of the inserted strings. Thus, building GST(*N*) from strings *(S<sub>1</sub>,..., S<sub>N</sub>)* with length *n<sub>1</sub>,...,n<sub>N</sub>* is:

> c(GST(*N*)) = *Σ<sub>i=1..N</sub> n<sub>i</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

If your generalized suffix tree is going to have only few strings in it, then you can concatenate them together in a single string using unique terminal symbols (these terminal symbols should not be used in input strings) between each strings.

For example, lets say you have 5 strings: str1, str2, str3, str4 and str5, then you can concatenate these 5 strings as str1$str2#str3@str4%str5 and then make a suffix tree of this concatenated string.

Since we MUST used unique terminal symbols so there would be a limitation on how many maximum string that could be added in generalized suffix tree. Any character which will NEVER be used in input strings, can be taken as terminal symbols.

So based on a predefined set of terminal symbols, we can write the code.

Following article may be helpful.

[Generalized Suffix Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generalized-suffix-tree-1/)

Comment: I already considered that option. However I was more looking for a mathematic proof to extend the original algorithm. And I'ld rather keep the _on-line_ property. I don't want to sound pedantic but the link you provided is not helpful (compared to Ukkonen's original paper)! Anyway thanks for your input :)