# Inserting new string to generalized suffix tree in linear time

Tags: data-structures, suffix-tree

If I have a generalized suffix tree and I want to insert a new string of length `m`, is it possible in `O(m)`?

(and the total lengths in the tree are `M >> m`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. If you are not familiar with it yet, I suggest you read about [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf).

Now suppose you have a *Generalized Suffix Tree* (denoted *GST* from now on) containing *N* strings. Then, you want to insert an *N+1*-th string *S*. I will assume that you have defined a terminal character for your strings (eg. `$`) and that this character will never be met in your input strings.

1. Append `$` to *S* (i.e. from now on we consider *S* to be `$` terminated)
2. Walk down the tree using the content of *S* until:

   1. The content of *S* is exhausted: this means the string *S* has already been inserted before
   2. A mismatch between a character in *S* and the content of the tree occurs

This first step will lead you to the starting point from where you need to work to edit the tree. It is obviously linear: *O(k)* when the mismatch occured at the *k*-th character of *S*.

Let us assume that *S* was not inserted before. The mismatch can occur in one of the following fashions:

- We end up in a node and cannot find a transition starting with *S's k*-th character.
- The mismatch occur in the middle of a transition, i.e. there is currently no node in the tree corresponding to the newly detected branching state.

This must remind you the iterative construction of a suffix tree and this is exactly it: we just need to point out the starting point and resume the tree construction (which will handle this dichotomy).

So you just have to resume the construction of the tree for *S* as if the *GST* was a common *Suffix Tree***<sup>(1)</sup>**. This construction is *O(m-k)*, so total complexity is *O(m-k + k) = O(m)*

**(1)**: Actually, it's a bit more complicated than that. In Ukkonen's algorithm, a substring of the string *S* represented by the *Suffix Tree* is basically a pair of indices *(start, end)* which denotes the first and the last character of the said substring. You need some additional machinery to keep Ukkonen's trick going when you consider a *GST* because *you have **more than one** string to refer to*. In other words, substrings needs to be attached to their reference string. More on that topic on this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278802/ukkonens-algorithm-for-generalized-suffix-trees).